# Can someone help get rid of this gap in IE? All other browsers all is well

Tags: html, css, iframe

Anyone out there able to help in figuring out the IE mystery of relieving this gap?  Has me and my team boggled as in how to get rid of it from Internet Explorer.  Seems to be fine in all other browsers that were tested in their latest versions (Firefox, Google Chrome, Opera & Safari).

I tried to set an image in the HTML using CSS, but then it applies to all the iFrames unless someone knows how to set an iframe image to either not appear or have a white background using CSS.  Seems that the 'background' attribute does not apply to iFrames.

Here is a link to the development site .. [dev576.webdugout.com](http://dev576.webdugout.com/images/112696/gap.jpg)

Hope I gave decent information for background.

Thanks in advance!

An image can be found below since I don't meet the requirements of this site :/

http://dev576.webdugout.com/images/112696/gap.jpg

Comment: Posting some code would help us debug your problem :)

Comment: Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and **include valid code to reproduce it** — in the question itself.

Comment: You use `float` and `position` way to much. You even mix them, which is almost always not what you want. This way, `body` has an empty height, which makes it almost impossible to debug.

Comment: @zeta it wasn't impossible for Minder Saini to debug.

Comment: @Shaun A link with modern browser developer tools is all the code you can get isn't ?

Comment: @jackncoke This website tends to frown upon linking to personal websites because it does not allow future users with the same problem who may view this page any help once the website has been fixed up.  If the code was posted here, the mistake could be captured and recorded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some problem with html inside footerwrap it got fixed when I apply overflow:hidden to id="pageContainer" or to footerwrap. so you can fix the issue by applying overflow:hidden to anyone of these 2.

Comment: Thanks!  Seems to be working in all browsers now with no issues.